# Merge contents of two lists alternately into one list in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to merge the contents of two lists alternately into a new list. The length of the lists are undefined. I am using the below code to achieve this. I want to know, if there is any groovy way to achieve this without using all the conditions and loop. The objective is to shorten the code as much as possible using groovy features.

```
def combineList(ArrayList list1, ArrayList list2){
    def list = [];
    int j = k = 0;
    def size = (list1.size() + list2.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(j < list1.size())
            list.add(list1.get(j++));
        if(k < list2.size())
            list.add(list2.get(k++));
    }
    println list;
}
```

**Input:**

*case 1:*

```
combineList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

*case 2:*

```
combineList([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

**Output:**

*case 1:*

```
[1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, 5, e, 6, f, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

*case 2:*

```
[1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways:

```
List combineList(List one, List two) {
    def result = [one, two].transpose()
    ( result += (one - result*.get(0)) ?: (two - result*.get(1)) ).flatten()
}

assert combineList([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d','e','f']) == [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 'e', 'f']
assert combineList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], ['a','b','c','d','e','f']) == [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 'e', 6, 'f', 7, 8, 9, 0]
assert combineList([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d']) == [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

**Explanation:**

- Transposing the lists results a list like `[[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]]`.
- Next check if there is any residual elements left in either of the list.

  - This is done by checking if a minus operation results with any elements. Take all first elements from result list to check against first list parameter, similarly take second elements of result list to check against second list passed as parameter to method.
- If present, then add them to the result
- Finally, flatten the result

Comment: I am learning groovy. Your solution seems puzzling now that I have learned about spread dot and elvis operator to understand it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It goes also simpler and slightly more performant:

```
def combineList( List o, List t ){
  def res = [ o, t ].transpose().flatten()
  int resSize = res.size() >> 1

  if( o.size() > resSize ) res += o[ resSize..-1 ]
  else if( t.size() > resSize ) res += t[ resSize..-1 ]

  res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java and Groovy does not differ a lot , one quick and easy to read  solution can be like this, for existing List l1 and l2

```
List list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator it = l1.iterator();
    Iterator it = l2.iterator();
    
    while(itA.hasNext() || itB.hasNext())
         {
          if(itA.hasNext())
          list3.add(itA.next());
          if(itB.hasNext())
          list3.add(itB.next());
        }
```